# ¿Cómo imprimo las salidas de la consola en una ventana?

Tags: python, tkinter, print, stdout

Supongamos que tenemos el siguiente código:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

raiz =Tk()
raiz.title("hola mundo")
miframe = Frame(raiz,bg="white",width="1000", height="650")
miframe.pack(fill ="both",expand = "True")

print("juan")
print("juan")
print("juan")
print("juan")

raiz.mainloop()
```

este código simplemente lanza una ventana en blanco y en consola me imprime el nombre de juan,yo lo que quiero es que juan sea impreso en un lugar determinado de la ventana que lance y no en la consola,es decir quiero saber como imprimir todas la salidas que se hacen por consola en la ventana.

Comment: se pueidera como adicionar a esa ventana algo como una consola donde me muestre todas las salidas que hago,algo como una pantalla y ver todo lo que se imprime en la consola de python,,,no se si esto se pueda ,disculpen mi ignorancia

Answer (score 1):

Para redirigir la salida estándar solo necesitas reasignar un objeto `sys.stdout` que implemente el método `write`:

```
import sys


class StdOutRedirect:
    def write(self,  out):
        # Hacer lo que sea con la cadena out


sys.stdout = StdOutRedirect(self.stdout_text)
```

Para mostrar el texto en tkinter, puedes usar un widget `Text`:

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk


class StdOutRedirect:
    def __init__(self,  text: tk.Text) -> None:
        self._text = text

    def write(self,  out: str) -> None:
        self._text.insert(tk.END,  out)


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent,  *args, **kwargs)
        self.stdout_text = tk.Text(
            self,  bg="black",  fg="#38B179",  font=("Helvetica", 15))
        self.stdout_text.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
        sys.stdout = StdOutRedirect(self.stdout_text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(root).pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

    print("Hola mundo")
    print("Hola Juan")
    print("StackOverflow")

    root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: aver eso esta bien pero al parecer no me explique bien,,esa ventana estara conformada por otros elementos como botones cuadros de texto ,etc y yo lo que quiero es que en una partecita de esa ventana  vallan saliendo todas esas salidas,,,yo en realidad lo que quiero es como crear una berve descripcion a medida que vas haciendo cosas,,por ejemplo si se introdujo un mobre en un cuadro de texto en esa ventana en un ladito diga se introdujo el nombre tal,,se como implemnetar esto para que me aprarezca en consola pero no en la ventana,,no se si me explico

Comment: Coloca el widget text donde quieras en la ventana, luego desde los métodos que quieras que informen (callbacks asociadas a los botones, a los Entries, etc) usa el método insert y envía el texto que quieras al widget.